# ¿Cómo pulsar dos teclas al mismo tiempo sin que una deje de funcionar en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, eventos

Tengo un problema en **tkinter**, cuando pulso dos teclas al mismo tiempo con el método `bind` o `bind_all` una de las dos no funciona.
 Además estoy haciendo un pequeño juego donde el personaje tiene que saltar mientras camina, y siempre o **salta** solamente o solamente **camina**.
aqui es el codigo de lo que mas o menos yo hago.

```
def saltar (event):
    for i in range (10):
        canvas.move (personaje,0,-1)
        ventana.update ()
        time.sleep(0.01)
def caminarAdelante (event):
    canvas.move(personaje,-1,0)
canvas.bind ("<Return>",saltar)
canvas.bind ("<repeat-Left>",caminarAdelante)
```

El codigo que se muestra aqui es mas sencillo del que enrealidad intente,pero es la misma base.

¿Hay alguna solución a esto sin la necesidad de descargar ninguna librería externa, solo librerias dentro de Python?

Muchas gracias a lo que respondan.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour], también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas. Debes colocar parte del código fuente así como también un [repro] para ver que avances has tenido y en que la comunidad te puede guiar.

Comment: No entiendo tu ejemplo. Para empezar, el sistema no debería de tener problemas si presionas dos teclas al mismo tiempo. Y segundo, el evento "repeat-Left" no existe. Podrías proporcionar un código tal que, copiado, pegado en mi editor y ejecutado me de el mismo problema que vos por favor? Asi, será más facil ayudarte.

Comment: es que yo uso un metodo que es usando `<KeyPress>` y `<KeyReleased>`. y bueno es mas complicado de entender ya que eso no es para interpretarlo de manera literal si no que es un ejemplo mas simple

Comment: Entiendo tu punto. La proxima te la tecnica usada en tu código original. Pero podría equivocarme. Reitero que si querés que te ayude con ese error, conviene más que publiques un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por cierto, no recibí notificación, te recomiendo usar el @DanteS. para notificarme.

Comment: Ups, recién me doy cuenta que que la primera oración quedó mal xD. Lo que quize decir, es que podría intentar adivinar la tecnica que usaste para hacer tu código, pero podría equivocarme.

Comment: lo que hice es que tengo un diccionario `movimientos={"Saltar":False,"derecha"=False}` ahora cuando usas `<KeyPress>` y se toca el boton,detecta que boton es,si es derecha:`movimiento ["derecha"]=True` y si sueltas la tecla lo detecta con `<Keyrealsed>` y vuelve ["derecha"]=False,hay una funcion que constantemente detecta si estos valores son `True` o `False` y si es `True` se meueve indefinidamente y si es `False` para de hacerlo.El problema se da cuando toco dos teclas a la vez,uno de los valores se detectara como inactivo y sera `False` y por ende deja de moverse,y no se porque pasa@DanteS

Comment: Me disculpo por el hiatus. Sinceramente, me cuesta entender lo que me dices. Insisto con que si quieres ayuda, crees un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable. Es la mejor forma de que entienda lo que haces.